# How to make CYPHERL file more human readable?

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb, opencypher, cypherl

I'm currently testing Memgraph(2.11.0) in docker. I have successfully imported my CYPHERL file via Memgraph Lab. However, it's very hard to read and maintain. Is it possible to improve that? Is there a document on the format any where?

Here's example of the CYPHERL file I have except that the WHERE clause in the real thing is longer.

```
CREATE (:EndPoint {service: "x-svc", owner: "x", method: "POST", path: "accounts/"});
CREATE (:EndPoint {service: "y-svc", owner: "y", method: "GET", path: "wallets/"});
CREATE (:EndPoint {service: "z-svc", owner: "z", method: "GET", path: "files/"});
CREATE (:DataSource {type: "mysql", name: "acc-db"});
MATCH (e:EndPoint), (e2:EndPoint) WHERE e.service = "x-svc" AND e.path = "accounts/" AND e2.service = "y-svc" AND e2.path = "wallets/" CREATE (e)-[:IS_CALLING]->(e2); 
MATCH (e:EndPoint), (d:DataSource) WHERE e.service = "x-svc" AND e.path = "accounts/" AND d.name = "acc-db" CREATE (e)-[:READ_FROM]->(d);
MATCH (e:EndPoint), (e2:EndPoint) WHERE e.service = "y-svc" AND e.path = "wallets/" AND e2.service = "z-svc" AND e2.path = "files/" CREATE (e)-[:IS_CALLING]->(e2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.cypherl` format is specific to Memgraph and is designed to house a series of Cypher queries to be executed sequentially. When you export data into a `.cypherl` file, Memgraph generates a series of Cypher queries, which, when run in the specified order, recreate the database's state. Memgraph utilizes the newline character to delineate the start of a new query; this means that you can't use new lines to break down single queries into multiple lines within a `.cypherl` file.

So you are not doing anything wrong. This just isn't supported at this time. You can open up an issues/feature request in [Memgraph GitHub repository](https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph) so that our developers can take this into consideration for future versions.

Discalimere: I work at Memgraph.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the `CYPHERL` file format is not explicitly documented anywhere (at least Google is not able to find anything).

But looking at the examples on [this Memgraph page](https://memgraph.com/docs/data-migration/cypherl), it seems a `CYPHERL` file just contains a number of opencypher statements, where each statement ends with a [semicolon](https://neo4j.com/developer/cypher/style-guide/#_semicolons). Each statement is executed as a separate query.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't play nice with new line. It seems to expect one continuous string. I tried to enter new line with "\" or in property of node but the import stop working then. Considering how Cypher command support multi-line, I was thinking I might do something wrong.